# Mixed data from two promises

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-promise

I have 2 services that return 2 promises, the first service return a list of objects, the second one returns the details for each object based on the id. So I need to invoke `service2` for each object returned from `service1`.
The loaded data will be saved in an array;

This is the way that I implemented but doesn't work

```
objects: object[];

service1.then(res => 
     objects = res.data;
     objects.forEach( obj =>
         loadService2(objId,(dtObj) => {obj = dtObj})
     )
);

loadService2(obj: object, callback: (detailsObject: DtlObject) => void){
    service2.then(res => callback(res.data););
}
```

This solution not work. After I still have the array of objects without details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
objects: object[];

service1.then(res => 
 objects = res.data;
 objects.forEach( obj =>
     loadService2(objId).then((dtObj) => {
        obj = dtObj
   })
 )
);

 loadService2(obj: object) => void){
 return service2(obj)
}
```

If this doesn't work

```
service1.then(res => 
 objects = res.data;
 let promiseses = objects.map( obj =>
     return loadService2(obj.objId));

Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
  objects = data;
 })
);

 loadService2(obj: object) {
    return service2(obj)
 }
```